# "Debug error" message in VS integrated Qt while calling a class function

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, pointers, visual-studio-debugging

Whenever I try to call any class functions in my Qt application, it crashes and shows this debug error.

For example, if I try to call this `getFile()` function, it should return a string, but the program crashes instead. I tried using a `char*` instead of a string, but then it stores garbage value instead of the actual value.

I'm using a base class pointer to store the derived classes here, which looks like this

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;
enum p_type { sclN, persN, n };

class notes
{
public:
    notes();
    notes(string title, string date, string t);
    string getFile() { return fp;}
    virtual p_type get_type();

private:
    string title;
    string date;
    string fp;
};

class personalNotes : public notes
{
private:

public:
    personalNotes();
    personalNotes(string title, string date, string t);
};

class schoolNotes : public notes
{
private:
    string category;
    string topicName;
    string subject;
    

public:
    schoolNotes();
    schoolNotes(string Cat, string Topic, string sub, string title, string date, string t);
};

p_type notes::get_type()
{
    if ( typeid(*this) == typeid(schoolNotes))
        return sclN;
    else if ( typeid(*this) == typeid(personalNotes))
        return persN;
    else
    {
        return n;
        //cerr << "\nNo such  type"; exit(1);
    }

}

notes::notes(string Title, string Date, string t) :title(Title), date(Date), fp(t)
{

}

personalNotes::personalNotes(string title, string date, string t) :notes(title, date, t) {

}

class dashboard
{

public:
    dashboard();

    string tf;
    void addPersonalNote(string title, string date);
    int rownumber;
    void submitFile();
    void writeToFile();
    notes* allNotes[1000];
};

void dashboard::writeToFile() {

    int size;
    ofstream ouf;
    p_type ptype;
    ouf.open("user.txt", ios::binary | ios::trunc);

    if (!ouf)
    {
        cout << "\nCan't open file\n"; return;
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < rownumber; j++)
    {
        ptype = allNotes[j]->get_type();
        ouf.write((char*)&ptype, sizeof(ptype));
        switch (ptype)
        {
        case sclN: size = sizeof(schoolNotes); break;
        case persN: size = sizeof(personalNotes); break;
        }
        ouf.write((char*)(allNotes[j]), size);
        if (!ouf)
        {
            cout << "\nCan't write to file\n";
            return;
        }
    }
    ouf.close();
}

dashboard::dashboard()
    : rownumber(0)
{
}

void dashboard::addPersonalNote(string title, string date)
{
    personalNotes tempPers(title, date, tf);
    allNotes[rownumber]=&tempPers;
    rownumber++;
}

void dashboard::submitFile() {
    tf = "this is a string";
}
int main()
{
    dashboard d;
    d.submitFile();
    d.addPersonalNote("this is title", "this is date");
    d.writeToFile();
}
```

and the notes array is in a dashboard class which looks like this `notes* allNotes[1000];`

But whenever I try to run the following function, it gives me this error

```
void dashboard::receiveDisplayImage(int num) {
    string kk = allNotes[num]->getFile();
    img = new image(this);
    img->finallyImageOutput(kk.c_str());
    
}
```

Whenever I call the `allNotes[num]->getFile()`, I get a debug error dialog:

[image: Debug error dialog]

I checked the class separately to see if it stores the information properly, and it does, and the array doesn't go out of scope either.

The program was working when I used individual vectors for each class that copied the *objects* themselves, and not the vector, it only started crashing when I used the base class pointers. For example, the following worked:

```cpp
vector<schoolNotes> sclNotes;
vector<personalNotes> persNotes;
```

But crashed when I used pointers.

Comment: Provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems).

Comment: How do you initialize the elements in `allNotes`?

Comment: I was initializing by creating a personalNote class via constructors and using num to assign it :
`personalNotes tempPers(title, date, tf);
allNotes[num]=&tempPers;`
here the num is just a count i was keeping while creating qt widgets
@G.M.

Comment: this problem only arises when i actually interact with the qt application i.e: press buttons, so i'm not sure i can provide a reproducible version of it :(( @user12002570

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] as previously requested.  My guess would be that in `allNotes[num]=&tempPers;` `tempPers` is locally scoped so you dereference dangling pointers and, hence, undefined behaviour.

Comment: Hi @G.M. can you please check now? i added a reproducible code

Comment: hi @user12002570 can you check please? i added a reproducible code

Comment: @mehreenhossain The program that you've added/updated won't compile because `ofstream ouf` is not valid. Kindly make sure(before posting) that the program that you post here, do compile and reproduce the exact problem you're observing so that other people don't have to spend/waste their time to first make the program compile. That is why we need  a minimal reproducible examples so that we can focus on your observed behavior/problem(which is a crash) without worrying about anything else.

Comment: did you try clicking "retry" to open the debugger? It should then show you where your code crashed

Comment: And if the place it shows you is not your code after you click retry you can use the call stack to find where in your code the problem started.

Comment: `personalNotes tempPers(title, date, tf); allNotes[rownumber]=&tempPers;` stores a pointer to a local variable that is destroyed when the function ends. This leaves a dangling pointer to nowhere and a ticking time bomb. https://godbolt.org/z/3Eh3E9W19 Minor note, but if you have over 100 lines of code in your example the least you can do is add the 5 lines of headers and using namespace std; so we don't have to.

Comment: You can't write and read non-trivial types like `std::string` like that. If it appears to work at all, it's just bad luck. Read about serialization.

Comment: Qt has support for searlization: [https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtserialization.html](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtserialization.html) a [QDataStream](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qdatastream.html) provides binary serialization.

Comment: @user12002570 i'm sorry this is the first time i'm posting a question so i didn't realize how exactly how i should post. i've managed to solve the problem by using serialization!! thanks for taking the time to answer and guide!!

Comment: @mehreenhossain Glad to hear that you solved the problem.

Comment: @RetiredNinja i'm really sorry, this is my first time posting a question so i didn't realize how i should post. i managed to fix the problem by serializing and removing the local pointer as you said! thanks for your help, it really means a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

managed to solve the problem!! thanks to everyone who commented and helped. i used serialization and stored variable by variable and removed some issues with the local pointers. here's the working code if anyone wanted to see:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;

enum p_type { sclN, persN, n };

class notes
{
public:
    notes(){}
    virtual ~notes(){}
    notes(string title, string date, string t);

    string getFile() { return fp;}
    string Gettitle() { return title; }
    void Settitle(string val) { title = val; }
    string Getdate() { return date; }
    virtual string get_type();
    virtual void serialize(ofstream& out) const
    {
        out << title << " " << date << " " << fp << " ";
    }

    virtual void deserialize(ifstream& in)
    {
        in >> title >> date >> fp;
    }

private:
    string title;
    string date;
    string fp;
};

class personalNotes : public notes
{
private:

public:
    personalNotes(){}
    personalNotes(string title, string date, string t);
    void serialize(ofstream& out) const override
    {
        notes::serialize(out);
        // Additional serialization for personalNotes
    }
    void deserialize(ifstream& in) override
    {
        notes::deserialize(in);
        // Additional deserialization for personalNotes
    }
};

class schoolNotes : public notes
{
private:
    string category;
    string topicName;
    string subject;


public:
    schoolNotes(){}
    void serialize(ofstream& out) const override
    {
        notes::serialize(out);
        out<<category<<" "<<topicName<<" "<<subject<<" ";
    }

    void deserialize(ifstream& in) override
    {
        notes::deserialize(in);
        in>>category>>topicName>>subject;
    }
    //schoolNotes(string Cat, string Topic, string sub, string title, string date, string t);

};

string notes::get_type()
{
    if ( typeid(*this) == typeid(schoolNotes))
        return "sclN";
    else if ( typeid(*this) == typeid(personalNotes))
        return "persN";
    else
    {
        return "n";
        //cerr << "\nNo such  type"; exit(1);
    }

}

notes::notes(string Title, string Date, string t) :title(Title), date(Date), fp(t)
{

}

personalNotes::personalNotes(string title, string date, string t) :notes(title, date, t) {

}

class dashboard
{

public:
    dashboard();
    ~dashboard();

    string tf;
    void addPersonalNote(string title, string date);
    int rownumber;
    void submitFile();
    void writeToFile();
    void readFromFile();
    notes* allNotes[1000];
};

void dashboard::readFromFile() {
    int size;
    string ptype;
    ifstream inf;
    inf.open("user.txt", ios::in);
    if (!inf)
    {
        cout<<"can't open file1"<<endl;
        return;
    }
    rownumber = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        //inf.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(ptype), sizeof(ptype));

        if (inf.eof()) { cout << rownumber<<" end of file" <<endl; break; }
        inf>>ptype;
        if (!inf)
        {
            cout<<"can't open file2"<<endl;
            return;
        }
        if (ptype=="sclN"){
            allNotes[rownumber] = new schoolNotes();
            size = sizeof(schoolNotes);}
        else if (ptype=="persN"){
            allNotes[rownumber] = new personalNotes();
            size = sizeof(personalNotes);
            cout<<"type detected"<<endl;}
        else cout<<"unknown class type"<<endl;

        allNotes[rownumber]->deserialize(inf);

        string t = allNotes[rownumber]->getFile();
        cout<<allNotes[rownumber]->Getdate()<<" "<<allNotes[rownumber]->getFile()<<"printed from read"<<endl;
        rownumber++;
    }
    inf.close();
}

void dashboard::writeToFile() {

    int size;
    ofstream ouf;
    //p_type ptype;
    ouf.open("user.txt", ios::binary | ios::trunc);

    if (!ouf)
    {
        cout << "\nCan't open file\n"; return;
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < rownumber; j++)
    {
        string ptype = allNotes[j]->get_type();
        //ouf.write((char*)ptype.c_str(), sizeof(ptype));
        ouf<<ptype<<" ";
        cout<<"ok";
        allNotes[j]->serialize(ouf);
        if (!ouf)
        {
            cout << "\nCan't write to file\n";
            return;
        }
    }
    cout<<"successfully written"<<endl;
    ouf.close();
}

dashboard::dashboard()
    : rownumber(0)
{
}

dashboard::~dashboard()
{
    for (int j = 0; j < rownumber; j++)
    {
        delete allNotes[j];
    }
}

void dashboard::addPersonalNote(string title, string date)
{
    allNotes[rownumber]= new personalNotes(title, date, tf);
    rownumber++;
}

void dashboard::submitFile() {
    tf = "this_is_a_string";
}
int main()
{
    dashboard d;
    d.readFromFile();
    cout<<d.allNotes[0]->getFile()<<"ok"<<endl;
    d.submitFile();
    d.addPersonalNote("this_is_title", "this_is_date");
    d.writeToFile();
}
```